# What's the best way to put form data in an array, pass them to a constructor, then insert into the database?

Tags: php, html, arrays, namespaces

```
 <!doctype html>

 <head>

</head>
 <body>
<?php
usemyNamespacemyNamespaceFile;
 require_once 'myNamespace/myNamespaceFile.php';

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 $formValue = array();
 $formValue = $_POST['name'];
 $formValue = $_POST['age']; . . . .
 }

 try
{
$formDetail = new getNewlyCreatedStuff($formValue);
throw new Exception("Opps! Something went wrong!");
}

catch(Ecxeption $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

 ?>
```

In my myNamespaceFile.php I'm grying to send the array to the constructor and use the array data to update the database like this:

```
 <?php
 namespacewestcoastchill;
 class EventDetail

{
protected $teamMatchResult = array();
protected $playerMatchResult = array();
public

function __construct($formValue)
    {
    define("DB_SERVER", "server");
    define("DB_USER", "username");
    define("DB_PASS", "password");
    define("DB_NAME", "dbName");

    // 1. Create a database connection

    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    // Test if connection succeeded

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")");
        }


    $query = "INSERT INTO myTable (
 userName,
 userAge
 )
 VALUES ('$formValue[0]','$formValue[1]')";
?>
```

These variables,$formValue[0] $formValue[1], are not initialized.  What is proper way to put form data in an array,pass them to a constructor, then insert into the database?  I've just used two variables here for simplicity but I have at least ten of these on the form.

Thanks for any help with this! Really appreciate it!

Comment: $_POST is already an array, why not just pass that?

Comment: Error message:  Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST.

Comment: Did you put $_POST as the name of your variable in the constructor? Just call it something like $formValues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very dumb of me...forgot to put the bracket that indicates an array $formValue[]= $_POST['name'];